# Deploy spring api with dokku: app container failed to start

Tags: spring, spring-boot, dokku

I'm trying to deploy my spring api with dokku in OVH vps, i fallowed this tutorial [https://github.com/kabisa/theguild.nl/blob/master/drafts/deploy-spring-boot-app-in-15-minutes/deploy-spring-boot-app-in-15-minutes.md]

but when i run git push dokku master i get this errors :
`

```
[INFO] Installing /tmp/build/pom.xml to /cache/.m2/repository/com/betroc/BeTrocRestApi/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/BeTrocRestApi-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
       [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
       [INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
       [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
       [INFO] Total time: 01:02 min
       [INFO] Finished at: 2018-12-28T22:11:54+00:00
       [INFO] Final Memory: 43M/120M
       [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types -> web
-----> Releasing betroc (dokku/betroc:latest)...
-----> Deploying betroc (dokku/betroc:latest)...
-----> Attempting to run scripts.dokku.predeploy from app.json (if defined)
-----> App Procfile file found (/home/dokku/betroc/DOKKU_PROCFILE)
-----> DOKKU_SCALE file not found in app image. Generating one based on Procfile...
-----> New DOKKU_SCALE file generated
=====> web=1
-----> Attempting pre-flight checks
       For more efficient zero downtime deployments, create a file CHECKS.
       See http://dokku.viewdocs.io/dokku/deployment/zero-downtime-deploys/ for examples
       CHECKS file not found in container: Running simple container check...
-----> Waiting for 10 seconds ...
460fb2b75b692724b3a27feeb997e0a825cdc822e08147cd9a35278c8fde33b7
remote: App container failed to start!!
=====> betroc web container output:
       Setting JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS defaults based on dyno size. Custom settings will override them.
       env: 'target/BeTrocRestApi-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar': Permission denied
       Setting JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS defaults based on dyno size. Custom settings will override them.
       env: 'target/BeTrocRestApi-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar': Permission denied
       Setting JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS defaults based on dyno size. Custom settings will override them.
       env: 'target/BeTrocRestApi-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar': Permission denied
       Setting JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS defaults based on dyno size. Custom settings will override them.
       env: 'target/BeTrocRestApi-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar': Permission denied
       Setting JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS defaults based on dyno size. Custom settings will override them.
       env: 'target/BeTrocRestApi-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar': Permission denied
       Setting JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS defaults based on dyno size. Custom settings will override them.
       env: 'target/BeTrocRestApi-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar': Permission denied
       Setting JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS defaults based on dyno size. Custom settings will override them.
       env: 'target/BeTrocRestApi-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar': Permission denied
=====> end betroc web container output
To dokku@ipXXXXX.ovh.net:betroc
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'dokku@ipXXXXX.ovh.net:betroc'
```

`

any ideas?

Comment: did you find a solution?

Comment: Check your repository adress in package.json(or which is your file )